# Having a little trouble with this Affine Cipher code

Tags: python

```
chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ,.".lower()
ext_alphabet = dict(zip(chars, range(len(chars))))
rev_alphabet = dict(zip(range(len(chars)), chars))

def find_coprime(a):
    for i in range(39):
        if ((i * a) % 39) == 1:
            return i

def encrypt():
    key1 = input("Enter the multiplictive key: ")
    key2 = input("Enter additive key: ")
    msg = raw_input("Enter message: ")
    ciphertext = [ rev_alphabet[(key1 * ext_alphabet[i] + key2) % 39] for i in msg ]   
    return ''.join(ciphertext)

def decrypt():
    key1 = input("Enter the additive key: ")
    key2 = input("Enter multiplictive key: ")
    msg = raw_input("Enter message: ")
    co_prime = find_coprime(key1)
    plaintext = [ rev_alphabet[(co_prime * (ext_alphabet[i] - key2)) % 39] for i in msg ]
    return ''.join(plaintext)



print encrypt()
```

There are two test cases given. The first one works, which is "happy coding" with a mult of 1 and an add of 9 but the second one doesn't work which is "today is feb 5,2015" with a mult of 2 and an add of 3. I have no idea why the second test case isn't working.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Can you paste in a test run of your program?

Answer (score 2):

Affine Ciphers cannot have the multiplicative value that is a factor of the 26 or the value 13.

The only allowed values are odd values. Therefore, `1,3,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,21,23,25`